# Customize email verification link issue in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, verification

I have admin portal and customer portal in my laravel based application

```
customer portal: customer.site
admin portal :admin.site
```

I have option to register for customers on my customer portal. Once an user register a verification email will be sent to user email with the verification link.

sample verification link can be like this: `http://customer.site/email/verify/10/2bf6330a5b3693fb6f5380e83e5494f82b87a9f8?expires=1588234415&signature=34ac37e86d1de7e316e717f2e1acf32cd4ee6ed97df56d94496bb2fa79a0f608`

so this works perfectly.

Now my issue is,

When I try to create a customer through the ADMIN portal (admin.site) the user creates successfully and the verification mail also sending successfully to the customer address. But, the activation link is something like this

```
http://admin.site/email/verify/10/2bf6330a5b3693fb6f5380e83e5494f82b87a9f8?expires=1588234415&signature=34ac37e86d1de7e316e717f2e1acf32cd4ee6ed97df56d94496bb2fa79a0f608
```

so when a cutomer clicks on that link a forbidden page displays sayin you have no permission to access as customers are not allowed to use the admin portal

How can I set that verification link to customer portal which is `customer.site` ???

This is my create customer function in the admin controller,

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        request()->validate([
            'name' => ['required', 'alpha','min:2', 'max:255'],
            'last_name' => ['required', 'alpha','min:2', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required','email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:12', 'confirmed','regex:/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{12,}$/'],
            'mobile'=>['required', 'regex:/^\+[0-9]?()[0-9](\s|\S)(\d[0-9]{8})$/','numeric','min:9'],
            'username'=>['required', 'string', 'min:4', 'max:10', 'unique:users'],   
            'roles'=>['required'],
            'user_roles'=>['required'],
        ]);

        //Customer::create($request->all());

        $input = $request->all();
        $input['password'] = Hash::make($input['password']);

        $user = User::create($input);
        $user->assignRole($request->input('roles'));

        event(new Registered($user));

        return redirect()->route('customers.index')
                        ->with('success','Customer created successfully. Verification email has been sent to user email.  ');
    }
```

I'm sending my verification mail from this

```
event(new Registered($user));
```

And in my `ENV` I even added a param called `APP_DOMAIN` ans set it's value to `http://customer.site`

also in my `app.php` I set this

```
'url' => env('APP_DOMAIN', 'http://customer.site'),
```

but still the activation mail link redirecting to `http://admin.site`

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried checking where that `admin.site` comes from?

Comment: it's my APP_URL in the env I can't cahange that attribute that's why I added an extra param called, APP_DOMAIN

Comment: Then I would assume that you should check where that is used. Maybe, it would be easier to run the whole application using the same host name?

Comment: I understand, but according to my requirement, once the user clicks on the verfication link, he should be redirecting to the customer portal not to the admin...currently he is redirecting to the admin and showing forbidden error..

Comment: That's fine, then let me repeat it: check where that URL is generated and exchange the host name there. You haven't provided any code that relates to sending an email

Comment: As i'm sending this email when a user creates by the admin , I used this method to sent the mail 'event(new Registered($user));' in the store function